# Error when archive app including widget

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios8-today-widget

When I want to archive app with the today extension I god this error:

chown: "Name": illegal user name
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1

what could be wrong ? My app with ext. working fine when I build to my iPhone

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my bad I wrote a wrong letter in my name